How to improve performance of http get API?
I am doing http get request from Service.
https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  downloadFile(URL) {
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}

If I am downloading my 500 MB file with above function then it will take around 30 seconds.
downloadFile(URL) {
        return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob'});
      }

With above changes it takes more time around 40 seconds.
What is the best way to get file data as BLOB with improved performance?
What we can do to improve performance on the Typescript/Angular side?

how big is the file? Are you using compression?

How long does it take to download the file if you just use plain browser download? Can't you use that directly? My thinking is that browsers should be quite good at this, i.e. buffer the file to disk.

His example file is 500mb @julaine

any client-side processing is going to create a clone... you should test against a normal file download... you can use a <form ngNoForm ...   (I would switch to respond to POST on backend.  GET may change URL?)  That'll stream the file and the browser will handle it.

Depending on how big your file is there's first multiple easy solutions to this UX problem:

Streaming: Send file in chunks and and process it on client-side again, with appropriate user feedback.
Client-Side: Optimize and reduce client-side logic to improve CPU, Memory and Network usage.
Compression: Compress the file server-side.

More advanced:

Consider using alternate protocols such as WebSockets or WebRTC.

